# Read many inputs at the same time in Python

Tags: python, input, python-3.x

I am making a program that read 2 or more input at the same time. How can I read input that has the form `a b`? For example: `3 4`. I need to read 2 variables: `a = 3` and `b = 4`.

Comment: What Python version are you using? 3.x or 2.x?

Comment: 3.x :) I just started learning Python. Can you tell me some books which you think are useful for absolute beginners?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like

```
a,b = input().split()
```

For example:

```
>>> a,b = input().split()
3 4
>>> a
'3'
>>> b
'4'
```

For reference, see [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) and [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

---

If you want `a` and `b` to be ints, you can call [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) (as is described in the comments):

```
a,b = map(int, input().split())
```

Comment: And if they needed to be `int`s, for example, you could wrap a `map` with an appropriate first argument around `input().split()`.

Comment: @icktoofay: (mentioning this just for completeness) or you could do a list comprehension: `[int(i) for i in input().split()]`

Comment: @user2727512 As the comments describe, `a,b = map(int, input().split())` would work.